# how do i Enable Text selection in Readonly/Disabled text field in FireFox browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a readonly text field in jsp as an input tag, I want to make a selection, copy the text and paste it for some further use.I am able to do it in IE browser but not able to do the same in FireFox. Please help. `<input name="ls_oma_data_alue.toimipaikkanimi" class="imp" id="Textfield3" type="text" size="55" readOnly="readonly" jQuery1316436638526="13" value="Kaunixxxxxxxxxxpunki"/>`

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876928/allow-copy-paste-in-a-disabled-input-text-box-in-firefox-browsers?rq=1 ?

Answer (score -1):

To keep it short: you can't access clipboard in Firefox (as oppose to IE). To make your script cross-browser you can use flash-based solution like this one: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: What does zero clipboard have to do with making a selection in a read only field? The poster is doing the copy paste manually, not with code.

Comment: Where in poser question you see statement that he's doing it manualy? If he's saying "I want to make a selection, copy the text and paste it for some further use" and its working for him in IE and doesn't in Firefox it leads me to quick assumption that he's trying to do that by code.