# how to make text area so we can only copy and paste in it not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to only copy and paste in `textarea` . I don't want to edit  in that `textarea`.

```html
<form action="save.php" method="post">

  <h3>Text:</h3>


  <textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605961/restrict-html-input-to-only-allow-paste

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict HTML input to only allow paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605961/restrict-html-input-to-only-allow-paste)

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent to press any key except <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd> like this:

**Allow:**

<kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd> Also <kbd>Copy</kbd> <kbd>Paste</kbd> button on `RightClick`

**DisAllow:**

<kbd>Everything</kbd>

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : ((e.keyCode === 17) ? true : false);
  if (e.keyCode === 86 && ctrl || e.keyCode === 67 && ctrl || e.keyCode === 88 && ctrl) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="50">Some Text</textarea>
```

Comment: Your `ctrl` variable can be defined in a simpler way: `var ctrl = e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode == 17`. Also, there is no need for an `if` clause: `return ctrl && (...||...||...)`

Answer (score 1):

disable the `keydown` event in the `textarea` on enable `mousedown` events
in that way we can force it to only copy/paste not to edit.

```js
$(".area").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  console.log('hello')
});
$(".area").bind("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log('world');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.touch {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Text:</h3>


<textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="50" class="area"></textarea>

<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the `keydown` on `textarea` on all keyboard keypress except <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>,  <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>,  <kbd>command+c</kbd>,  <kbd>command+v</kbd> keys.

Use `event.metaKey` for the mac <kbd>command</kbd> key.

*<sup>Try to copy the text of textarea using <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> or paste any text inside it using <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd></sup>*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("text");

textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var key = event.key;
  var cmd_key = event.metaKey;
  var ctrl_key = event.ctrlKey;
  if ((cmd_key && key == "c") || (ctrl_key && key == "c")) {
    return true;
  } else if ((cmd_key && key == "v") || (ctrl_key && key == "v")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <h3>Text:</h3>
  <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="50">Copy this text and paste</textarea>
  <br><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Abhishek Singh's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48840940) example; in ES6 with arrow functions and jQuery it can be as succinct as:

```
$textarea = jQuery("<textarea>")
     .on("keypress", (e) => e.ctrlKey && e.key == "v")
```

(Similar story but with "c" for preventing anything but copy)