# How to disable typing but allow copy and paste in a text box in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-decorator

I want to restrict typing in a text box but I need to paste anything inside that textbox in Angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605961/restrict-html-input-to-only-allow-paste check out this

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the event propagation if the combination pressed is different than the one you choose.

You can do it like this:

```js
public onInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  //if is pressed a different key than c or v, or the ctrl key isn't pressed stop event
  if (!event.ctrlKey || (event.key.toLowerCase() !== 'c' && event.key.toLowerCase() !== 'v')) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  } 

  // else execute the default event behaviour
}
```

```html
<input type="text" (keydown)="onInput($event)">
```

Hope it helps. ^^

P.S.: You have to use the event keydown for this to work.