# disable field but allow to put the cursor on it and allow to copy from it

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following text box which having a value inside of it but it is disabled.
the problem is that this textbox have value inside which I want to allow that the user
can copy the value from it,the problem is currently that I cannot put the curser on it...
any idea how to solve it?i've tried also with read only and having same issue...

```
<td class="display-field">
<b>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EString, new { @style = "width: 100px;", placeholder = "Click", @disabled = true })</b>                            
 </td>
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876928/allow-copy-paste-in-a-disabled-input-text-box-in-firefox-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cursor:pointer; in inline style and readonly="true"
check this

```
<input  style = "width:100px;cursor:pointer;"  readonly ="true" value="hellohellohell"/>
```

Comment: Thanks ,there is a ways that I can do that with arrow also?

Comment: cursor:default;
Jean Tehhe

Answer (score 0):

readonly not working?

```
<td class="display-field">
    <b>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EString, new { @style = "width: 100px;",  placeholder = "Click", @readonly = "readonly" })</b>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`readonly="readonly"` will let you copy the text from textbox and won't let you edit text.