# How to disable user selection on disabled input box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to disable user selection on a input box which is disabled.

I have used `pointer-events:none` css property to prevent selection on input box

It is working fine if I apply the css to an input box which is not disabled.

But for some reason it is not working to the input box which is disabled. Please take a look at the code below

```html
<input type="text" disabled value="do not select" style="pointer-events: none;"/>
```

Tried  `user-select:none` even this didn't work.

**Edit**: Pointer-events:none is working fine in firefox, but it is not working in chrome.

Comment: I think you should be looking at `user-select: none`

Comment: even that didn't work, I tried already :( @Terry

Comment: What're you trying to achieve? It's not clear in your question. What do you mean by "prevent selection on input box" then?

Comment: I'll be showing some text inside a text box and disable the input box based on the my clients requirement. 
As it is some sensitive content I was asked to prevent selection on it so that no one can copy the text.

Comment: @Harish could you include browsers affected? It seems that text in disabled input field with both pointer-events:none and user-select: none remains selectable in Chrome only.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice this. pointer-events:none is working fine in firefox. Only in chrome I'm facing this issue. @myf

Comment: It seems it is really a Chrome bug: currently setting `pointer-events:none` on *enabled* input prevents mouse selection, but has no effect on *disabled* - truly amusing, maybe even worth reporting. (There is interesting info in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356009/540955 btw.)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a little CSS trick with covering the `:disabled` with another transparent element.

```js
onselectstart = (e) => {e.preventDefault()} // total page select disabling, just to make sure
```

```css
.input-cover {
  position: relative; 
}
.for-disabled {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
input:disabled + .for-disabled{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-cover">
  <input type="text" disabled value="do not select" />
  <div class="for-disabled"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-cover">
  <input type="text" value="select please" />
  <div class="for-disabled"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `style="pointer-events: none;"` specifically, disabled does the job for you. As it's disabled all the selection related properties are disabled due the disabled attribute. I think **removing** `style="pointer-events: none;"` is gonna solve your purpose.

Comment: I might be wrong, I just analyzed your question and share my thoughts.

Comment: just an input box with disabled attribute doesn't prevent selection on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my previous answer didn't work, I also tryed

```
<input id="my_input" type="text" value="Try to select me!" disabled unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"/>
```

But this doesn't work for disabled fields as well, perhaps you could just set it to readonly?

---

I think that you should try using `user-select: none`, more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting).
I'd comment this but I still don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Even that property didn't work on disabled input box