# Having a input readonly i cannot copy value

Tags: html, google-chrome, readonly, readonly-attribute

I'm having trouble with input text that are readonly and have a placholder text.
I cannot copy the text in chrome.

- If the text is selected with the mouse and then CTRL + C, the text is not copied
- If the text is double-clicked and then CTRL + C, the text is copied
- If the text with double click of mouse and in the context menu of the mouse is selected the option to copy, the text is copied

```html
<p>If the text is selected with the mouse and then CTRL + C, the text is not copied</p>
<p>If the text is double-clicked and then CTRL + C, the text is copied</p>
<p>
If the text with double click of mouse and in the context menu of the mouse is selected the option to copy, the text is copied</p>


<form>
<input type="text" value="123" placeholder="123" readonly="readonly"/></form>
```

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/sjtwdov3/26/

I tried searching for this problem but couldn't find any help.
Have you encountered any of this? Is this a known chrome issue.

Comment: Selecting and copying worked for me

Comment: If I click and drag to highlight the text and press Ctrl + C it copies for me.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876928/allow-copy-paste-in-a-disabled-input-text-box-in-firefox-browsers

Comment: Perhaps someone can provide a clean solution, but put simply, the issue you are having is a result of the focus state not being applied to the input when you highlight the text.

Answer (score 0):

Editted - Since it's being passed through a form use a hidden field below with a name attribute to pass the value through the form.

```
<input type="text" value="123" placeholder="123" disabled />
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="fieldName" />
```

Comment: I updated my question to have the input sorrounded by a form. The problem with disabled, is that some browsers (like firefox)  disable the copy feature if the input is disabled

Comment: Yes that is true.  A possible solution would be to have a hidden input beneath the disabled input like so:
<input type="text" value="123" placeholder="123" disabled />
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="fieldName" />

Also note that I added a name attribute to the hidden field, so that it's value is accessible by the form handler. (Sorry I am new to S/O, not sure how to format code in comments)